# how to insert image array using fpdf+php

Tags: php, fpdf

i'm trying to use fdpf with php to generate a pdf file with patient automatic reports system

so after getting all patient info from DB .. i'm trying to print report image from directory

```
$id=$user_id;
$dir="./user_reports/$id";
opendir("$dir");
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$report_img=array();
for($k=1;$k<=iterator_count($fi);$k++)     // iterator_count to count files in folder
{
    $report_img[$k]="$dir/$id.jpg";
    $id++;
}
```

and this is to print info.

```
for($x=1;$x<=$i;$x++)
{
    $image=$report_img[$x];
    $pdf->Cell( 40, 40, $pdf->Image($image,70,190,-300), 0, 0, 'L', false );
}
```

after all .. it doesn't work :(

any ideas?

Comment: Please specify "it doesn't work". Where's the problem? Any errors reported?

Comment: No specific error .. This library doesn't print errors .. If it works the PDF will be generated .. Else it won't load at all this is the problem

Comment: You need to switch on error reporting. Try to include this at the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Remember, making one syntax error in your main script might cause you to only see a blank page in your browser, even with the above line in your script.

Comment: it's already switched on .. it's http error 500

https://i.imgur.com/E1oOcDQ.png

Comment: Ah, a server error. Check the Apache and PHP logs for errors, or comment out sections of your code to find out what causes this.

Comment: yes this what i did already

these two lines causing the problem

`$image=$report_img[$x];
    $pdf->Cell( 40, 40, $pdf->Image($image,70,190,-300), 0, 0, 'L', false );`

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming `$pdf->Image($image,70,190,-300)` returns a string which you can put in a cell. This is not so. Try this:

```
for($x=1;$x<=$i;$x++)
{
    $image=$report_img[$x];
    $pdf->Image($image,70,190,300);
}
```

I left out the cell, because it doesn't do anything. I used a positive width for the image.

I'm sure this doesn't do what you want. That's unclear at this point, but it shouldn't generate an error 500 anymore, as long as the images exist.

Generating a PDF file like this is nothing like working with HTML. You're probably thinking of HTML table cells.

In the case you want to print something, you can work with just HTML. It is now possible to make pages in HTML and set the true dimensions when printing with styles. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size

That could be a much better solution for you, since you seem to know HTML. It wouldn't work if it is actually the PDF file you want.

Comment: unfortunately not working :(

but i'll try to use HTML as you said